# Java encoding for Japanese characters

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, cjk

I have a file name with Japanese characters. file name: `S－最終条件.pdf`. In Java, file name: `S－最終条件.pdf`.

```
// Support for Japanese file name
fileNameX = new String(fileName.getBytes("Shift_JIS"),"ISO8859_1");
```

The output `fileNameX` is coming out `S?最終条件.pdf`. Hence it is throwing an error. I am trying to outstream the file in PDF format, but the particular Japanese character "－" is not recognised and it is throwing error while streaming.

Please help me solve this issue.
Thanks, Prasanna

Comment: Try Using `UTF-8` instead of `ISO8859-1`.

Comment: I tried UTF-8, but it is not working. having the same error

Comment: It looks like you are encoding `fileName` with one charset and decoding with another. I really don't see the point of this. Why can't you just work with `fileName` directly?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what your code actually does:

```
//Assign to bytes the UTF-16 String fileName Encoded in Shift_JIS
//bytes now contains the binary Shift_JIS representation of your String
final byte[] bytes = fileName.getBytes("Shift_JIS");

//Create a new String UTF-16 by interpreting bytes as ISO8859_1
//Takes the Shift_JIS encoded bytes and interprets it as ISO8859_1
new String(bytes,"ISO8859_1");
```

Java strings use UTF-16 for their internal representation. You cannot specify a target encoding when you create a string as UTF-16 is fixed, you have to Specify the correct source encoding which is "Shift_JIS" for the bytes array.

The fileNameX should come out correct without converting.

Answer (score 1):

This is the mapping problem both Shift_JIS code and Unicode.
Shift_JIS doesn't have all the characters of Unicode so some characters become "?".

Following is the result of conversion from Unicode to Shift_JIS.

```
RESULT  UNICODE
[NG]    U+2012 (FIGURE DASH)
[NG]    U+2013 (EN DASH)
<OK>    U+2014 (EM DASH)
[NG]    U+2015 (HORIZONTAL BAR)
<OK>    U+2212 (MINUS SIGN)
[NG]    U+FF0D (FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS)
```

One solution is a replacement of the code.

```
U+2012,U+2013,U+2015 --> U+2014
U+FF0D               --> U+2212
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answers by @josefx and @Yu Sun corn are both collect.

First, as @josefx answered, when you want the Shift JIS representation of a string and reverse it to a `String` object, you have to pass the same encoding to `String#getBytes(String charsetName)` and the constructor `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`.

Second, you have to use `Windows-31J` instead of `Shift_JIS` as the encoding name. The encoding scheme of `Windows-31J` and `Shift_JIS` are the same, but the character set is slightly different: Windows-31J has some additional characters (Note that Windows-31J in Windows document is called "Shift JIS". So in most cases, you should use `Windows-31J` when you want to use Shift JIS). As @Yu Sun corn answered, the string `"S－最終条件.pdf"` contains a character that is not contained in the character set of Shift JIS: `－`. The character set of Windows-31J contains this character.

Finally, the code you should use will be like this:

```java
// Get the byte-stream representation of Japanese characters in Windows-31J encoding.
// Windows-31J (aka MS932) is the default encoding when you run Java VM in Windows with Japanese locale.
byte [] textBytes = name.getBytes("Windows-31J");

// Reverse byte-stream representation to a String object
System.out.println(new String(textBytes, "Windows-31J"));
```